# How do you determine if the current field is required from a fieldtype class?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

I need to run validation in a custom fieldtype but only if a field is required.

How do you determine if the current field is required from within a fieldtype class?

Answer (score 1):

In Craft 1/2, there isn't a particularly clean or easy way to do this because `$this->model->required` is only set in the context of when it's being called from a field layout.

In the context of a field type, Craft doesn't set it because `required` is a concept that belongs to a field layout and a given field can belong to multiple field layouts.

This whole process has been refactored and is much cleaner in Craft 3 so that `$this->model->required` works in the context of a field type where you'd expect it to.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't play ball for me, it returns false whatever the field setting. Calling it from within a custom validate() method, that should work right?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Any way to work around this one pre Craft 3?